# What to do with identical commits in Git?

Tags: git, version-control

When I'm using Git, I've run into this error:

Error parsing revisions: **e4fff73d6f29a243af63ef0a1a2bff1054d1d2ca** warning refname '**develop**' is ambiguous.

I used the command `git show-ref`  which gave me a list of the commit for the repository. I found that I had this:

```
e4fff73d6f29a243af63ef0a1a2bff1054d1d2ca refs/tags/develop
e4fff73d6f29a243af63ef0a1a2bff1054d1d2ca refs/tags/origin
```

It appears that I do indeed have two commits with the same hash. Additionally, just to add to the confusion, there is a branch which is called **develop** in the current Git repository.

My question is this:

How do I either merge, delete or just plain fix this issue so that I no longer have Git warn me about the ambiguous references?

Comment: Those two items you listed are tags, and shouldn't conflict with each other. You can have as many tags as you want on a single commit. Do you also have a branch named develop? I'm wondering if it's getting confused between the branch and the tag.

Comment: @Dave - Yes, there is also a branch called develop.

Comment: Are the `develop` branch and tag already both public? If one of them is not, just rename it; that should remove the ambiguity that Git is complaining about.

Comment: @Jubobs - yes the tags have been committed and pushed to the develop branch. Upon further research, they all seemed to happen to the same commit by the same user. There have been about a dozen more commits since that one particular check-in happened.

Comment: @Chris Please specify the Git command that gives rise to the error in question.

Comment: @Jubobs, the warning appears when I open up GitGui and I want to visualize the branches history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments, there is only the one commit with that ID; but there are multiple names for that commit (which is allowed, and even normal in some cases, although not this particular one).

The error message appears to come from `gitk` (that's the only piece of git source that has the literal string `Error parsing revisions:` in it) and if so, is due to the warning message—gitk assumes that any warning message must be an actual error, even though this one is just a warning.

The key to the *warning* is here:

> just to add to the confusion, there is a branch which is called **develop** ...

This means the unadorned name `develop` might mean either the *tag* `develop`, or the *branch* `develop`.  Git is warning you that you'll get one, and you might have meant the other.  According to [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), in this particular case you get the tag (however, that's not true for an explicit `git checkout` command, which—for valid reasons—has its own different rules for deciding whether to treat a name as a branch name).

The cure for the warning is simple: decide whether that should be a tag (if so, rename or delete the branch name) or a branch (if so, rename or delete the tag name).  Most likely, the branch name is the right one and the tag is wrong, so "just" rename or delete the tag.

The problem with the cure—changing the tag name—is that git generally assumes that tag names are permanent and global.  If you're using a shared repository, chances are you picked up the tag name from someone else.  If you rename or delete *your* tag, you may well pick up the tag again from them, like some sort of touch-transmitted disease.  To properly fix it you must<sup>1</sup> "cure" both your own repository *and* any repository you `fetch` from.  If that's a central server repository others use for `fetch` and `push` operations, you probably have to cure it too, and if it picked up and dispensed the "disease" to other developers, you may need to have them "heal" their repositories.

What this really boils down to is a broadcast email to all developers: "oops, sorry, bad tag in repository, please rename or delete" (and maybe fix it on the server—well, *someone* has to fix it there, but that might be someone with better access, and maybe even put in a pre-receive or update hook to reject attempts to "re-infect" the server).

---

<sup>1</sup>The word "must" is actually quite a bit too strong.  Git won't fetch all tags unless you tell it to, e.g., with `git fetch --tags` or by fancying-up your `.git/config` file. By default, it brings over a tag at the same time it brings over the commit to which the tag points.  So as long as you already have `648cc593ebe85617cc7dda6b0c126dbbf020a230`, your git will not feel the need to re-create tag `develop`.  Similarly, `git push` won't push tags unless directed.

Nonetheless, if *you* have a bogus tag, chances are someone else does too, unless of course you're the one who created it in the first place.  So, as with certain diseases, it tends to be wise to follow up with your partners.

Comment: In the end I had to do git tag -d develop and git push origin :refs/tags/develop in a couple of different places. Once those commands were executed, things seemed to settle back down to normal. Thanks for explaining what was going on with my repo.